# Python Try: Syntax Error

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying to set up a python program to edit a database from input from my arduino, and the `try:` command is giving me an error and I'm not sure I understand why

```
import serial
import MySQLdb

dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","Mecool100","ISEF_DB") or die ("Could not connect to database")
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = '/dev/ttyACM0'

try:
    print "Trying...",device
    arduino = serial.Serial(device, 250000)
except:
    print "Failed to connect on",device

try:
    data = arduino.readline() #read data
    pieces = data.split("\t")

try:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = data”)
    dbConn.commit()
    cursor.close()
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    print "Failed to insert data"
finally:
    cursor.close()
except:
    print "Failed to get data"
```

This code is returning the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 21
    try:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could someone please assist me in finding my error?

Thank you :)

Comment: You did not put `except` clause after our previous line `pieces = data.split("\t")`

Comment: You can't have a `try` without an `except`/`else`/`finally`.

Answer (score 2):

The others who are saying that you need `except` blocks after your `try` are right...but they're missing that you already have them. Really, the problem is that this line

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = data”)
```

should be this:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = data")
```

`”` is in fact not the same character as `"`; it is codepoint 146 in [CP1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (sometimes incorrectly called ANSI) or codepoint 8221 in Unicode. Do `chr("”")` to see for yourself.

You also need to indent the third `try` block, so in the end, your code should look like this:

```
import serial
import MySQLdb

dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","Mecool100","ISEF_DB") or die ("Could not connect to database")
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = '/dev/ttyACM0'

try:
    print "Trying...",device
    arduino = serial.Serial(device, 250000)
except:
    print "Failed to connect on",device

try:
    data = arduino.readline() #read data
    pieces = data.split("\t")

    try:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = data")
        dbConn.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print "Failed to insert data"
    finally:
        cursor.close()
except:
    print "Failed to get data"
```

Comment: The OP has a proper `try..except`, then a `try` with no `except`, then a `try` with its `except..finally` accidentally in a string, then a hanging `except`. So no, they don't already have them, even accounting for the smart quote issue.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I assumed that the third `try` was supposed to be indented, and when the corresponding `except` and `finally` blocks are indented too, the hanging `except` matches up with the second `try`. Take a look at the `print` statements and you'll see that's how it was intended.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `except` and/or `finally` block for the second `try:` block.  A `try` without an `except` or `finally` does not make sense, so the extra block is compulsory by syntax.

In your third `try` block, you should move the `except` ahead of the `finally`.

Additionally, you have a gnarly quote character on this line:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE `ISEF_DB`.`attendance` SET `present`='1' WHERE `id` = data”)
```

Make sure it's a `"` in your code, not a `”`.

Answer (score 0):

every try statement must have an except clause

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("oops")
```

Comment: On the contrary, you can do a `try - finally`.